# jenkins kubernetes-plugin slaveConnectTimeout not honoured

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

i am running jenkins  2.103 in docker and have connected it to a kubernetes on arm cluster.
i have been able to manually connect the jnlp (v3.16) slave to the master, however it appears to take around 15mins for it to fully connect and report as online. Once online I can run builds as expected.
The problem is that it appears the 'slaveConnectTimeout' setting in the podTemplate is not honoured in the pipeline configuration, and neither is the default template setting of 'Timeout in seconds for Jenkins connection' in Pod Template section of Global Settings.

has anyone be able to make this setting work, and, does anyone have any idea what could be causing the 15min delay in registration?

this issue has been raised as a bug [JENKINS-49281](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49281) now as well.

Comment: without logs it is impossible to know

Answer (score 1):

the issue ended up being openjdk and me not fully understanding what the kubernetes timeout is all about.
the delay in agent registration is not just a jenkins issue, i have seen the same behaviour in gocd and other java based apps. platform issue, not app issue